# Can this query be modified to include an offset?

Tags: sql

Currently using an Excel form with some basic VBA to pass data between end users and a SQL table.  I'm running into a bit of a problem though, where the users may wish to skip the record they're being presented, and get the next one.  Because I've got 3 users (currently) sharing the data, I need to be sure Person A and Person B aren't conflicting each other.  I do this by updating a status field to "LOCKED" as soon as User A receives her data.

Anyway, I've been trying to figure out how the OFFSET works, but am not having much luck.

The abridged version of the statement:

```
Select top 1 ID,Query,Status from mydb.mytable where status = 'NEW' order by Priority desc
```

That gives me the highest priority record in NEW status.  A second statement runs to update "NEW" to "LOCKED"

But if the user can't handle the record, she needs a different one.  I thought something like the below would work, but I just can't get it to work.

```
Select top 1 ID,Query,Status from mydb.mytable where status = 'NEW' order by Priority desc offset 5;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you forgot the keyword ROWS after 5, it should be ORDER BY Priority DESC OFFSET 5 ROWS. Could you give this a try?

Comment: Thank you for that Kevin.
I did try it, and am at least now getting a meaningful error message: "A TOP can not be used in the same query or sub-query as a OFFSET."

I can work with that now.  Thank you again!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm just using microsoft sql server management studio.  I have nearly no idea what I'm doing!

Comment: Why is "OFFSET 5" used? Why 5 specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) :

> TOP cannot be combined with OFFSET and FETCH in the same query
>   expression (in the same query scope).

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2012 or above, this is what you can do instead.

```
SELECT ID, Query, Status FROM mydb.mytable 
WHERE status = 'NEW' 
ORDER BY Priority DESC
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

The `FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY` will give you the very first row after offset, which is equivalent to what you'd get by doing `TOP 1`.